# starting new activity with map from main activity

Tags: android, android-activity, google-maps-api-2

I have a problem with switching activity from MainActivity to MapsActivity.
GoogleMap shows only cached maps. But when I change in manifest that ActivityMaps is configured as action.Main and category.LAUNCHER everything is working fine. What's the problem?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <permission
        android:name="pl.mototravel.mototrave.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="pl.mototravel.mototrave.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".map.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
private void showMap() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

MapsActivity.java:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements     OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
```

build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
```

Api:

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 25
```

activity_maps.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:contex="my.app.map.MapsActivity"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean it only shows cached maps? I've created a project just as you've described, and I don't see any odd behavior thus far.

Comment: I have SplashActivity( checking connection with server and user session), If user session is valid then I switch to DashboardActivity. In drawer menu I have option show map, after click map is not loading.. but when I change in manifest that MapActivity is a MainActivity everything is working fine.